# How create retrofit2.Response with custom object as body?

Tags: android, retrofit2, okhttp

In Android application I use Retrofit2 to execute http requests.
It's work fine.

Also to create error Response I use this:

```
import okhttp3.MediaType
import okhttp3.Protocol
import okhttp3.Request
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import retrofit2.Response

   private val CODE_TEMPLATE = "[CODE_TEMPLATE]"   
   private val MESSAGE_TEMPLATE = "[MESSAGE_TEMPLATE]"
   private val templateBody =
                    "{\n" + "\"code\": $CODE_TEMPLATE,\n" + "\"message\": \"$MESSAGE_TEMPLATE\"\n" + "}"

          private fun createTransportErrorResponse(
                    code: Int = defaultCode,
                    message: String = defaultMessage
                ): Response<*> {
                    val body =
                        templateBody.replace(CODE_TEMPLATE, "$code").replace(MESSAGE_TEMPLATE, "$message")
                    val rawResponse = okhttp3.Response.Builder()
                        .code(code)
                        .message(message)
                        .protocol(Protocol.HTTP_1_1)
                        .request(Request.Builder().url(BuildConfig.API_BASE_URL).build())
                        .build()
                    val responseBody = ResponseBody.create(
                        MediaType.parse("application/json"),
                        body
                    )
                    val errorResponse = Response.error<Response<*>>(responseBody, rawResponse)
                    return errorResponse
                }
            }
```

As you can see as **body** I use json. Nice. It's work fine.

The question is:

Is it possible to use in body my custom object like this:

```
class Bonus {
    var id: Int = 0
    var balance: Double = 0.0
    var name: String = ""
    }
```

I need `Response.body` to be **my custom** object (`Bonus`)

?

Comment: yes you can do .

Comment: @RajasekaranM Do you have any example? Thanks

Comment: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-send-objects-in-request-body

Comment: @RajasekaranM I need my custom object in Response.body not in Request.body

Comment: do you mean `Response.success(Bonus())` ?

Comment: @Fred yes I need my custom object  "Bonus" as body

Comment: @a_subscriber so I guess that's the answer? Or what am I missing?

Comment: @Fred yes, this is as answer but with my custom object as response's body

Comment: @a_subscriber, I'm sorry but I'm not getting that part. Is `Bonus` not your custom object?

Comment: @Fred "Bonus" is my custom object

Comment: @a_subscriber so `Response.success(Bonus())` should create a success response where `.body()` is you custom object.